# What does it mean when a compareTo method returns 8136?

Tags: java, compareto

So the code in question is:

```
int result = stringArray.get(4).compareTo("The");
System.out.println(result);
```

and it prints out:
    8136

I am confused because from what I can tell, `compareTo()` returns 0, 10, or -10.

Comment: _"I am confused because from what I can tell, compareTo() returns 0, 10, or -10"_ I don't know where you made this assumption. The doc clearly tells _" Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."_.

Answer (score 7):

The general contract of [`Comparable.compareTo(o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) is to return a positive integer if `this` is greater than the other object.

Whether it is 1 or 8136, what matters is that it is a positive integer and your code should only depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int result = "Thf".compareTo("The");
    System.out.println(result);
    result = "Thg".compareTo("The");
```

results in

```
  1

  2
```

so there must be ascii difference of 8136 between stringArray.get(4) and "The". Having positive means first > second.

Are you using a language pack consisting of more than 8000 different characters?

Maybe its differentiating hashcodes

```
    int z11="\\vs".hashCode();
    int z22="The".hashCode();

    System.out.println(z11-z22);
```

gives 8136

Comment: I wouldn't depend on any of that, as it can vary from JRE to JRE and is not necessarily consistent, not even during between two calls in the JVM. [As Tunaki already pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28638629/4585628), the only thing one can rely on is the contract, which states _positive result = left > right_.